# C# How run Threads with Async methods in command line app

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, async-await

I simple do not know how to make the following code work, it is suppose to keep running forever inside an infinite loop, and in fact it will work when I remove `await Task.Delay` from the method `Method_FOO`, but I need `Method_FOO` to be async.

I think to make this work the `Thread.Start()` method needs to be "waitable" (not just the code it runs), but Thread.Start is void. I notice that if I block the execution with eg.: `Console.ReadLine` it will print the `Worked` string, but this is not a solution, and is terrible in real life.

This code is just an example, but the threads need to run inside an infinite loop (it is not something I can change), and I need async methods because I need to consume some websockets, and looks like there is no sync client websocket class in C#.

But still, there must be a simple/decent solution for this problem.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var thread1 = new Thread(async () => await Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName1", Method_FOO));
        var thread2 = new Thread(async () => await Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName2", Method_FOO));

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
    }
    
    private static async Task Method_FOO(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is called...");
        await Task.Delay(300, cancellationToken); 
        //never reach this part
        Console.WriteLine("Worked  ...");
    }

    // workd but it is not async
    //private static  Task Method_FOO(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("It is called...");
    //   Console.WriteLine("Worked  ...");
    //    return Task.CompletedTask;
    //}


    private static async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string threadName, Func<CancellationToken, Task> function)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await function(cancellationToken);
                Console.WriteLine($"{threadName} waiting ...");
                cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread don't wait task's end. When the 3 threads (main, thread1, thread2), the program is closed and running task killed.

You can make the method `Run` synchronous and manualy wait the task end, like :

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var thread1 = new Thread(() => Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName1", Method_FOO));
        var thread2 = new Thread(() => Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName2", Method_FOO));

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
    }

    private static async Task Method_FOO(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is called...");
        await Task.Delay(300, cancellationToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Worked  ...");
    }

    private static void Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string threadName, Func<CancellationToken, Task> function)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                function(cancellationToken).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine($"{threadName} waiting ...");
                cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : Why not directly use the tasks?

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task1 = Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName1", Method_FOO);
    var task2 = Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName2", Method_FOO);

    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ContinueWith(t => cancellationTokenSource.Cancel());
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Comment: It is a big system and there are threads everywhere, unfortunately it is not an option

Answer (score 6):

At this point in history, `new Thread` is pretty much only useful for COM interop. In every other scenario, there are better solutions. In this case, you can send work to the thread pool by using `Task.Run`:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var task1 = Task.Run(async () => await Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName1", Method_FOO));
  var task2 = Task.Run(async () => await Run(cancellationTokenSource.Token, "threadName2", Method_FOO));

  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, as someone who uses COM interop every now and then: What's the COM interop use case that requires `new Thread` instead of `Task.Run`?

Comment: Can you explain the interest to encapsulate the task returned by `Run` in other task?

Comment: @Heinzi: I recommend using a manual Thread if you need to set apartment states and do pumping.

Comment: @vernou: This kind of code is a "start several background workers" kind of architecture. Tossing each one on a thread pool thread is a way to ensure that if any of them have synchronous startup, then that wouldn't affect any other background workers.